# Opening all posts for comments

Tags: comments

Is it possible to use the user-interface (front-end) part of Wordpress to open comments on all posts in one (or two) clicks?  I have many posts with closed comments which must have happened by mistake, and I want to make them all open comments.

Here's the caveat:  My host provider doesn't give me `ssh` access into the database, so I can't just run a simple sql `REPLACE` command. Therefore, I need a way to do this from the Administration Panel within wordpress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote up this quick plugin that updates all posts of type `post` to `comment_status` `open` on activation, it should work for you. you can immediately deactivate and delete it once you activate it that once.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: update comment status
*/
function activate_update_comment_status() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update( 
        $wpdb->posts, 
        array( 
            'comment_status' => 'open'
        ), 
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post'
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s'
        ), 
        array(
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_update_comment_status' );
```

Comment: This works perfectly on v5.2.2 in 2019. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Just because this method is so out dated, here's a modern solution.

In the wp-admin under Posts when you see the list of all your posts, check the box next to Title so that all your posts are selected.  Then choose the bulk option Edit.  From here you can change all your comments to Allow in the select box.  Then click update.  This now allowed comments on all your posts at once.

Comment: How would I do that if I have 6000 posts? The plugin method above works perfectly.